# understanding property decorator in python

Tags: python

I have a class defined as this:

```
class ClientAPi

   def __init__(self, host): 
      self.host = host

   def foo(self, foo):
      return self._foo(foo)
   @property
   def _foo(self):
     return bind_api(
            api=self,
            path='/foo',
            allowed_param=['foo'])
```

where bind_api is https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy/blob/master/tweepy/binder.py
actually.. this is the pattern in tweepy library 
https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy/blob/master/tweepy/api.py

How does this works? I am unable to understand the flow..
I mean how does the variable foo is transmitted from foo() to _foo()..?

Also, now.. some of the paths for my api has changed.. 
instead of `host:port/foo` now it is `host:port/v1/foo`
Is there a way I can annotate these methods with some decorator..such that methods which have this decorator has its `path='/foo'` to `path=/v1/foo`

So for example

```
class ClientAPi

   def __init__(self, host): 
      self.host = host

   def foo(self, foo):
      return self._foo(foo)

   @new_api('v1')
   @property
   def _foo(self):
     return bind_api(
            api=self,
            path='/foo',
            allowed_param=['foo'])
```

changes path from `'/foo'` to `'/v1/foo'`

Comment: possible duplicate of [How does the @property decorator work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17330160/how-does-the-property-decorator-work)

Comment: I don't think your `new_api` decorator can be made to work, since it would need to somehow alter constants set inside the function's code.

Comment: @metatoaster :Can any one explain to me that when I do the call self._foo(foo) in function foo.. but the _foo(self) function doesnt accepts any arguments.. how do i catch the args which I am passing from the main function to property function?

Comment: Look at the [code that you linked](https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy/blob/master/tweepy/binder.py#L238) and see that the return object is `_call` which is a function that can be called.